# I am able to add a link to readme file but not able to add a link to other files in the repo

Tags: git, github, repository, commit, readme

[I have created links , but it appears as normal text after committing the change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSTh2.png)

I am expecting the link the be created when I commit the changes in the github file just like I am able to add the link in readme file

Comment: What OS are you working on? What commands are you using to create and commit the links?

Comment: Looks like a MarkDown-style link. If you create a file with extension `md`, commit it, push it to GitHub, then view it on GitHub then, yes, it should be rendered as a link.